# std::span.size() vs array/vector size

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

We are playing around with `std::span()` (using the gsl implementation for now) at work.  Recently we discovered that comparing a `std::span.size()` to a `vector.size()` was giving a `-Wsign-compare error`:

```
if( span.size() > vector.size() ) // comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

I don't think we want to cast at every one of these comparisons.  Our coding guidelines treat these warnings as errors.  Curious if anyone has any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. As of now `span.size()` returns `index_type` which is a `ptrdiff_t`. A signed size is necessary for having `std::dynamic_extent` work. You'll probably have to cast. To be honest, a better solution would be to just make it `size_t(-1)` just like `std::string::npos` for example.

Comment: My project uses a home grown `signed_cast` and `unsigned_cast` to do sign conversion, and will throw if the cast cannot be made.  Keeps the same size. So for example, an unsigned short `us` with `signed_cast(us)` becomes a signed short (for example, 16-bit short), and if between 0x8000 to 0xFFFF will throw.  Maybe something like that would be suitable for your purposes?

Comment: Recently (https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/commit/691a78c016408c74a689c35359e4c7e313501808) `gsl::span` was aligned with C++20 `std::span` and now `size()` returns `size_t`, not `ptrdiff_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use iterators and have both use the function [`std::distance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

```
if (std::distance(s.begin(), s.end()) > std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()))
```